# Titan graph database re-indexing procedure

Tags: solr, cassandra, titan, reindex

I have used Titan graph database with Cassandra and Solr in production environment. Currently our application is deployed and minor down-time is acceptable. Unfortunately due to some changes in schema we need to re-index the whole Titan graph instance. What is the best way of re-indexing process with considering these concerns:

- Minor down-time would be acceptable.
- Classic Solr schema is used and due to space efficiency all fields were considered with `store="false"`. (except the ID)
- We have some hard-coded id indexing in Solr. (for making some of the aggregation queries more efficiently by indexing some of the vertex-IDs in Solr.) Therefore, the cost of solutions that might change vertex-id is high.

Comment: Ali: how did you solve this problem? Did you follow the reindex guide and did you hit any problems with it? http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-admin.html

Comment: @Guy Yeah. I did follow this instruction.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @Guy Yes it did. However, we got some inconsistency issues inside indexes.

Comment: Do you remember what the inconsistencies were?